# MVC4 nested forms with validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I haven't been able to find a good answer on the interweb so asking here.

I have a regular non-ajax form (Html.BeginForm) and within that form I want to have several ajax forms.

Let me give you the scenario.

I have a rather big/large shopping cart / checkout form. In that form the user will be able to  select four different options (radiobuttons) (four different forms for each of the options - 1. Register 2. Login 3. some other function 4. some other function). 
So in that big form I want to have 4 smallar forms. What is the proper way to achieve this?

Also note that all 5 forms (big form + 4 smallar ones) - they all need to have their own viewmodel so to speak. and they also need to have their own validation capabilities - that is - they must trigger their own validation rules independently of each other.

Comment: nested forms are not valid markup, Ajax.BeginForm still emits a form tag. Consider having a single form and dynamically loading the relevant parts based on radio button selection

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that nested forms is a no no. I use jquery to load each form dynamically based on user selection. it works fine. however - i cant seem to figure out how to validate the ajax forms properly. dont really know how to write the viewmodel.. tried to add Username and Password fields with [Required] attribute but that breaks the big form.. so basically I need to have different viewmodels/models for each of the forms, correct?

Comment: try reparsing the validations of the dynamically loaded form content and rather than calling $('form').valid() or $(document).valid() when you submit, try only validating the container for the "sub form" i.e. $('#subformid').valid()

Comment: @nakchak getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'element' of undefined jquery.validate.js:94 on this line if ($("#tab2_step1").valid()) { // ajax method } ?! because it's a div and not a form element??

Comment: I'm going to reiterate nakchak's comment.  Nested forms aren't valid.  It doesn't matter if you dynamically load them or not.  What you are looking for is typically called validation groups.  You have to choose either to forgo the big form and submit it yourself via javascript, or forgo the inner forms and handle the ajax yourself.

Comment: This thread my help you with one approach, assuming you don't want to find or write your own validation groups logic: http://forums.asp.net/t/1698991.aspx/1/10

Comment: Checked the thread from asp.net forum but that solutionn doesn't feel very MVC to be honest.. There has to be a better way? PartialViews? With their own model?